# DNS taking weeks to propagate just in my area

Tags: dns, nameserver, dns-servers

It has been over two weeks since I changed over my DNS information on my new host. I still have my old hosting account setup through HostGator and it is still using the HostGator nameservers in my area.

I have checked with DNS tools and it is showing that in every other area it is using the new DNS info.

I have done an NS Lookup and it is still showing HostGator nameservers, so my browser is ruled out. I have flushed my DNS on my computer and restarted it, so that is ruled out. I have restarted my router and modem, but still have the same results.

Now one would think that it is just my ISP, although here is the thing...I have attempted to go to the domain on two of my mobile devices, both using different mobile networks, with WiFi turned off and STILL got the same nameservers and the old page on the site. If that isn't enough I tried at the office which again uses a different ISP and low and behold, it is still using the old DNS info.

My new host and all the DNS proxy tools confirmed everything is as it should be and pointed to the new nameservers.

So why is this happening only in my area? Is there anything I can do about this? I am losing valuable time waiting for what seems like eternity; it will be 2.5 weeks tomorrow.

Comment: Are there any errors being returned by _online DNS health checks_ (do a search on that term)?

Comment: I did a check earlier today, and it came back with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Be sure to check several different ones, paying special attention to the nameservers returned in their details, and contact your DNS provider/hosting company's tech support for assistance (they may need to reset it on their end).

Answer (score 3):

It's weird to have such a long propagation delay. Most probably there is a problem with it! Anyways, first run the command

```
nslookup <yourdomain.com> <dns-server-ip>
```

on your PC with different dns servers like

```
nslookup yourdomain.com 4.2.2.4
nslookup yourdomain.com 8.8.8.8
```

for Google and Public DNS servers, and you may like to check http://dns.yandex.com/ for more tests. Don't forget to check it with your area DNS servers, too.

If you get the old information from any of the tests, you have to report it to your hosting provider. For example if all `nslookup`s show new information, but your own ISP don't, provide all the details to your hosting provider, so that they can fix it sooner.

Once I had such a problem and it was because of a wrong firewall rule on the authorative DNS server which was blocking some other DNS servers!

Comment: I have actually done all of that, nslookup on my end shows old servers on my actual cloud server it shows the new server. The cloud hosting technicians confirmed it and looked into it and said nothing is wrong. I checked using many dns propagation tools and they all say that the servers have propagated. The thing is when checking anywhere via nslookup they haven't(using different ISP's). It makes no sense whatsoever. Since there is nothing wrong apparently, no one can do anything.

Comment: Isn't your country blocking something!?